# Joomla - File permissions & owner for a website under version control (svn)

Tags: linux, apache, svn, joomla, file-permissions

What's the correct `file owner` to use `locally` for a `joomla` project, which is under `svn`?

When all my files are owned by `apache` user, I cant update my project from `svn` (& I cant edit these files with my `normal user`).
And when my files are owned by my `normal user`, `joomla administration (Information tab)` shows that some directories are `read-only`.  Should I change only the owner of these directories (`plugins`, `tmp`...) to `apache` user, and let the other files owned by my `user`?

I have to find a compromise between the two users (`apache` & `normal user`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should use a different user for each site, and use the same user for svn/git.

But assuming that's not possible, keep in mind that Joomla *needs* to write to the folders below.  Additionally, without a write access to images, you won't be able to upload images.

So the list of files/folders to assign to the apache user is:

- administrator/cache
- cache
- logs
- tmp
- configuration.php
- images

All the other files can be owned by the svn user; however you'll need to chmod / chown when you want to update Joomla from the backend, and install new extensions.

An easier approach is to keep only your component under svn (you can checkout only the paths you want with svn easily) and leave the rest to apache.

Finally, consider putting your svn user and Apache in the same user group, and chmod to 775.

Comment: I will change the owner of the directories (admin, cache...) to `apache` user. And add my user to same group as `apache` user. Finally, I have to change permissions of all directories to `775` and files to `664`, is it correct?

Comment: Yes that should do, just remember you'd better write a shell script as you'll need to run updates from the frontend, which will reassign the property to the apache user.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this complete differently because this is really a pain, pushing files from a Joomla installation back to a repo. Assuming you're local,

1. change in /etc/passwd for apache or www-data the shell from bin/sh to bin/bash.
2. fix the permissions of the home directory (usually /var/www ) for www-data, so that www-data can create its .svn directory. thats done by # chown -hR www-data /var/www
3. as root change to www-data : # sudo su www-data
4. go to the joomla installation/folder with the svn meta files
5. call svn info or whatever, so that it can store the svn credentials in .svn
6. you're done here, now you can call via php/system svn update in whatever folder

i've written this here www.xappcommander.com also for Joomla for exactly for this purpose  which allows you to change code in an active joomla installation push back the changes to a repo without all the pain of the alternatives (sftp/ftp). Through its shell extension, you simply write #svn ci --message="whatever".

this works well also in a live stage, under plesk PHP is running with your user account, so you skip step 1-4.